# Остановка скрипта и восстановления его работы

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. 
Задача следующая, есть большая выгрузка товаров, проблема заключается в том, что при загрузке картинок, а их примерно несколько тысяч ~7000-8000, сервер не успевает обработать все это дело, что и логично.

Как можно остановить скрипт, например после 100 загрузок картинок, а потом его восстановить на моменте остановки.

Мое предположение, что можно записать во временный файл весь массив картинок с ключом, потом for`ом бежать и когда он добежал до 100 делать перезагрузку страницы, но уже в GET передавать на каком месте мы остановились и бежать уже от того места. Тобишь получается, пробежали мы первые 100 товаров, дальше передали параметр script.php?id=100 и уже от 100 бежим до 200 и так до конца пока массив не закончится.

Вопрос, насколько правильные мои предположения или можно, что-то проще придумать?

**UPD**

Выгрузка с чужого сервака в свою базу

Comment: выгрузка на страницу? с базы?

Comment: @Vlad Vlad с чужого сервака в свою базу

Comment: У img повесить событие onready или onload, можно повесить обработчик, что б присваивал там из src2 в src url-ку на следующей картинке по событию в текущей. Все теги img тоже выбираются через js.

Comment: @Komar то есть ты парсишь картинки с чужого сайта?

Comment: @nick_n_a я так понял он парсит через php картинки с другого сайта и у него отваливается скрипт по timeout'у

Comment: @EatMyDust приходит XML поставщика, она лежит у них на серваке, они дают ссылку вида 
ftp://ftp_drive_d_r:zP3CxVm4O8kg5UWkG5D@178.159.255.108:41/d8b2cc2a-c75c-11e2-8cb0-005056ad2cf4___Porcelanite-Dos-400.JPG

Comment: если данный скрипт не являеться частью полноценного проэкта, и нацелен только на узконаправленное действие, то я думаю, что и ваш вариант подойдет, можно к смещение добавить еще количество (за один проход) загружаемых файлов

Comment: `сервер не успевает обработать все это дело` - а что случается с сервером, он устаёт и уходит в отпуск?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое правильное решение загрузки данных с сервера поставщика на свой сервер - консольный скрипт, который не имеет timeout, в отличие от веб-сервера. Запуск такого скрипта из консоли позволит обработать все записи. 
Второй вариант - записывать в сессию номер последней обработанной записи от сервера-поставщика и при каждом последующем запуске скрипта продолжать обработку после этой записи.

Comment: Самое печальное, что клиент хочет, чтоб скрипт отрабатывал как и по крону, так и чтоб он сам го запускал, думаю обучить его консоли будет не просто

Comment: @Komar можно поднять Jenkins и научить клиента тыкать кнопочку )

Comment: Сделайте страницу, которая будет записывать команду на запуск скрипта в файл или бд. Запускайте скрипт по крону, который будет читать этот файл или таблицу бд и запускать скрипт загрузки, если запуск был назначен. Запускать скрипт из браузера != смотреть как он выполняется и отвал по таймауту.

Answer (score -1):

Для решения похожей задачи использовал следующий скрипт:

```
<?php
    // Здесь получаем список картинок, которые нужно загрузить - все 8000.
    // Дальше считаем, что список содержит урл картинки.
    $images = listImages();

    // CACHE_IMAGES - файл с кешем уже загруженных картинок.
    // Если кеш уже существует, то загружаем его в память, если нет
    // то создаём пустой кеш.
    if(file_exists(CACHE_IMAGES)) {
        $newUrls = unserialize(file_get_contents(CACHE_IMAGES));
    } else {
        $newUrls = array();
    }

    // Счётчик загруженных картинок в текущем запуске.
    $i = 1;
    // Пробегаемся в цикле по всем картинкам, которые нужно загрузить.
    foreach($images as $image) {
        // Если в кеше уже есть картинка, то пропускаем её загрузку.
        if(array_key_exists($image, $newUrls)) {
            continue;
        }

        // Если уже загрузили 100 картинок, то завершаем обработку картинок.
        if($i++ > 100) {
            break;
        }

        // Отмечаем загруженную картинку в кеше.
        $newUrls[$image] = 1;

        // Собственно, загружаем картинку.
        downloadImage($image);
    }

    // Сохраняем кеш картинов обратно в файл для следующего запуска
    file_put_contents(CACHE_IMAGES, serialize($newUrls));
?>
```

Скрипт удобно запускать по крону (я так и делал), но можно и из браузера. Важное условие - нельзя допускать одновременной работы нескольких экземпляров скрипта.

На основе приведённого кода можно сделать разные вариации - хранить кеш в базе; не хранить кеш совсем, а проверять уже загруженные картинки (на диске или в базе) и т. п.

Загружать в любом случае лучше небольшими порциями (даже при запуске из консоли), чтобы не забить свой канал и не положить чужой сервер.

Comment: Ставите минус - пишите комментарий, что не так.

Comment: я не ставил, так что не ко мне)